# Migrating To Weblogic From Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I have a web application running on tomcat. I want to deploy it on a weblogic server but i get some problems.

```
Error(s) found in module 'BatchMonitoring'. Publish was cancelled. See "Problems" view for details.
  Target runtime SpringSource dm Server (Runtime) v1.0 is not defined. at BatchMonitoring
  Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. at BatchMonitoring




java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find state with id 'displayError' in flow 'admin_main' -- Known state ids are 'array<String>['queryAll', 'mainForm', 'register']'
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.getStateInstance(Flow.java:348)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.DefaultTargetStateResolver.resolveTargetState(DefaultTargetStateResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:217)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.handle(TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.java:110)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowExecutionExceptionHandlerSet.handleException
```

Comment: How did dmServer get in there?

Comment: It is impossible to say anything about your problems, you are just not providing enough details (no useful trace, no logs, nothing).

Comment: How did the project facet get there? that's eclipse internal stuff.

Comment: Do you know how to create a domain in weblogic ?
What development tools are you using ?
Can you list how you are deploying ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you had problems with Java versions of what Tomcat is using(points to JAVA_HOME) at environmental variable and JDK of Weblogic. Also it would be good if you send some logs and exception messages.

Comment: there are no logs or exceptions
when i try to run it using eclipse, an error dialogue will op-up stating that deploying was stopped bec of the reasons i have stated above

Comment: Check in WebLogic user_projects directory for logs
D:\bea\user_projects\domains\{$UserDomain}\servers\AdminServer\logs

Comment: I added a portion of the log above. This exception occurs only n the weblogic server. My projects works well in tomcat. I saw a sample project running in weblogic. It has a weblogic.xml. So that means I have to saetup first the project to run in weblogic and not just simply run it in the weblogic server. I guess the problem is I need to set it up first. I have no idea how

Comment: Assuming you had successfully installed Weblogic ,create a domain with your project,then deploy the application and then test it.(Assume this is a ear or war type).Which version are you using

Comment: I just deploy the application through eclipse. I add a new server then browse for the domain instance of the web logic server. The I just build the application and choose run on server

Comment: I looked at the logs and found this

weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [Deployer:149003]

can't paste the rest. it's in nihongo